# How clone duplicate existing project in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I have one Project in SonarQube with some history and some Confirmed Issues and I need split this project, because of two versions of source code, but I need the history and Issue changes in both projects. How to do this? It is possible somehow clone, duplicate existing Project to another one with different name?

Answer (score 0):

Cloning or duplicating a project is not supported.

You can use the [Time machine functionality](http://www.sonarqube.org/sonar-time-machine-replaying-the-past/) of SQ to "recreate" the past analyses of the project under another name but it won't recreate the history of changes on issues.